# SQL Query to fetch salary and distinct no of employees geting that sal from emp table

Tags: sql

fetch sal and distinct no of employees geting that sal from emp...whts the query?
table name-emp
columns-empno,ename,sal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select 
    emp.Salary, COUNT(*) 
from 
    emp 
GROUP BY 
    emp.Salary

Will return a distinct list of Salaries and the number of Employees who have that salary, provided that Salary and Employee are both contained on a communal table (can't tell from the question wording).

Try expanding your question a little to get a better response.

Comment: fetch sal and distinct no of employees geting that sal from emp...whts the query? table name-emp columns-empno,ename,sal